Are quadruples $abcd$ and $dcba$ always projectively equivalent in any projective plane?
It is well-known that for every line $L$ in a Pappian projective plane (i.e., a projective plane over a field) and any distinct points $a,b,c,d\in L$ the quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(d,c,b,a)$ are projectively equivalent, i.e., $P:(a,b,c,d)\mapsto (d,c,b,a)$ for some line projectivity $P:L\to L$.

Question. Is this fact true in any projective plane (not necessarily Pappian or Desarguesian)?

By a line projectivity in a projective plane $X$ I understand a finite composition of line perspectivities. A line perspectivity between lines $L,\Lambda$ is a central projection from $P_o:L\to\Lambda$ with some center $o\in X\setminus L\cup\Lambda$. The central projection $P_o$ maps every point $x\in L$ to the unique point $y\in\Lambda\cap\overline{ox}$, where $\overline{ox}$ is the line passing through the points $o$ and $x$.
Added in Edit: It can be shown (by suitable calculation) that for every quadruples of distinct points $a,b,c,d$ on a line in a Desarguesian projective plane, the quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(d,c,b,a)$ are projectively equivalent. On the other hand, for every finite non-Desarguesian plane $X$ of order $\ne 23$, by a theorem of Grudhofer (1988), the group of projective collineations of any line in $X$ is isomorphic either to the symmetric group of the alternating group on $L$. Since $X$ is not Desarguesian, $|L|\ge 10$, which implies that for any distinct points $a,b,c,d\in L$ the quadrples $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(d,c,b,a)$ are projectively equivalent. Therefore, the question only remains for infinite projective planes and for finite projective planes or order $23$ (there is a well-known conjecture that every projective plane of prime order (including 23) is Desarguesian).

Is this true over a skew field?

@FedorPetrov I do not know. But it can be calculated, at least. Because every  projectivity between lines in a Desarguesian projective plane is the composition of three line perspectivities. So, some algebraic formulas for line perspectivities can be deduced and then the problem can be solved algebraically. Thank you for the suggestion. Maybe the same algebraic approach will work also in Moufang planes, which is sufficient for my purposes.

are there invariants of projections similar to cross ratio over skew fields? Since three points may be always sent to three points, it can be reduced to the invariance of this non-commutative cross-ratio under this change of ordering

@FedorPetrov There is a characterization of Pappian projective planes as planes on which a line projectivity is uniquely determined by three points, so for non-Pappian projective planes, I would not be very optimistic about the existence of certain projective invariant (like the cross-ratio). But nonetheless, the quadruples $abcd$ and $dcba$ could be projectively equivalent.

@FedorPetrov I have just calculated and indeed, the quadruples abcd and dcba are projectively equivalent in Desarguesian projective planes and (very probably) in Moufang projective planes, too. In a translation plane over a quasifield, any line quadruples $abcd,dcba$ are projectively equivalent if the identity $(1-x)^{-1}(x^{-1}-1)=x^{-1}$ holds in the quasifield. For this the quasifield should be distributive (from both sides), which is not true in some quasifields, for example $J_9$.

@FedorPetrov So, it can happen that in the Hall projective plane (of order 9, constructed on the near-field $J_9$) some quadruples $abcd$ and $dcba$ could be not projectively equivalent.
